# Prepend file content to match in sed

Tags: text, sed

I am trying to append the content of a file *before* the closing body tag in an html document. I've tried

```
cat test.html | sed  -e $'/<\/body>/{ r insert.html ... }'
```

using various combinations of \np, \nd at ..., but everything seems to be inserted *after* the tag.

It would also be nice if additional string constants could be added around the content of insert.html, such as centering tags etc.

Comment: I'd say you are using wrong tool here.. use html/xml parsers or programming language with modules for html/xml..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `sed` is your hard requirement, you can try this in `GNU sed`:

```
sed '/<\/body>/e cat insert.html' test.html
```

It uses GNU-specific [`e shell-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands) (`e cat filename` here), which will, unlike `r filename` be executed *before* the end of the current cycle (before `</body>` line is processed/printed).

---

Note (from the docs) [`r filename`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Read-text-from-a-file) will:

> Queue the contents of filename to be read and inserted into the output stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next input line is read.

and [`e command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-e-_0028evaluate_0029-command):

> [...] unlike the `r command`, the output of the command will be printed immediately; the `r command` instead delays the output to the end of the current cycle.